# C: Command line arguments with string

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write a program that takes a string as a command line argument and then runs said argument through a function (str_to_int) that takes a string as an input. However, when I try to compile the program, I get a warning saying

```
initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint
conversion]
  char* str = atoi(argv[1]);
    ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And when I run the program I get a segmentation fault
I've tested the str_to_int a lot so I'm pretty sure that the issue lies with the command line program. Here's the code for it.

```
#include "hw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char* str = atoi(argv[1]);
  printf("%d\n", str_to_int(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `atoi` returns an `int`.

Comment: Your code takes a string (`argv[1]`), converts it to an `int` (`atoi()`), puts the result in a string (`char*`), which will mess things up, and then converts it to an `int` (`str_to_int()`). What's the goal here?!

Comment: remyabel and Biffen (and the compiler :-) ) are right.

Comment: So how do I get read a string from the command line?

Comment: @dmeagher101 I think it should be fine if you just leave out the `atoi`.

Comment: `atoi` means `Ascii TO Integer`.

Comment: Command line arguments start out as strings. What did you think they were?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need, though it will crash if you leave out the command-line argument.

```
{
    printf("%d\n", str_to_int(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

This is more robust:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
        printf("missing parameter.");
    else
        printf("%d\n", str_to_int(argv[1]));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1st one does not necessarily crash, depends on `str_to_int` and if accepts null pointer as valid argument, or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "hw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char* str = argv[1];
  printf("%d\n", str_to_int(str));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove `atoi` function invocation and it should work